# Date format gets changed when comparing?

Tags: android, date

Here is my code

```
if (cs1.moveToFirst()) {
                                    curr_date = cs1.getString(0);
                                    exp_date = cs1.getString(1);
                                    account_activation_status = cs1
                                            .getString(2);
                                    status_flag = cs1.getString(3);
                                    Log.e("dates", ">" + cs1.getString(0)
                                            + "   " + cs1.getString(1));
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("dates", "no table>" + cs1.getString(0)
                                            + "   " + cs1.getString(1));
                                }
                                try {
                                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                    formattedDateTime = df.format(c.getTime());
                                    date1 = df.parse(curr_date);
                                    date2 = df.parse(exp_date);
                                    date3 = df.parse(formattedDateTime);
                                    Log.e("dates", "date1=" + date1
                                            + " date2=" + date2+" date3="+date3);
                                    boolean dateNew1=date3.getTime() < date2.getTime();

                                    if (date3.getTime() < date2.getTime()
                                            && (!status_flag.matches("D"))
                                            && (!account_activation_status
                                                    .matches("0"))) {
                                        Log.d("expiry", ">1="+status_flag+" 2="+account_activation_status+" 14="+dateNew1);
                                        Log.e("4", "4");
                                        button_yes.setEnabled(true);}
                          else{
                               none}
```

What I am facing is even though I am converting the date to the particular format(i.e dd-MM-yyyy),In some cases I will get like (yyyy-MM-dd). and my condition get false...need help thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify that cases?

Comment: make sure your values cur_date and exp_date are stored in dd-MM-yyyy format.

Comment: @PiyushGupta...I get current date and exp date from server,I store it in a variables.no matter what ever the format I get,I will change it to particular format.In some cases like when I don't get success from server,the date format of the exp_date variable get changes.I have no idea why it get changed.even though I am converting it to the particular format.